# Why my '/home' route is accessible only for authenticated users?

Tags: laravel

So I have a home route ( '/' or '/home' ) and for some reason this route ca be accessed only for logged in users.

I have not set this route to be for authenticated users only, therefore I have no idea why is it working like this.

The routes look like :

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

There are some routes in the application that are supposed to be accessed by registered users only. In their case I added this to the route : `middleware('auth')`

Does anyone have a clue why my home route requires authentication?

Comment: arent they grouped in a rout group?

Comment: No, or at least it was not done by me.

Comment: These routes may be in a route group with `auth` middleware assigned. The `auth` middleware can be assigned in `HomeController` constructor.

Comment: Two different places where you can have the auth middleware assigned are: App\Http\Kernal in the property $middlewareGroups  or in the RouteServiceProvider in the method mapWebRoutes. But it is unlike that you changed here.
Check the `php artisan route:list` to see which kind of middleware you get in this routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check you controller constructor and remove the middle-ware there. Use Auth middle-ware only on routes not on controller.

Your **HomeController** might have Auth middleware check on its constructor method.

Your constructor should like:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth'); //Comment this line
    }
```

Create route group in your route file and specify auth middleware there.